# How to read JSON data file

Tags: java, eclipse

How to read this JSON file in Java?

```
"paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/6604386669/posts?fields=shares,created_time,permalink_url&limit=25&format=json&since=1489024832&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBACipMCOGXLzMceEqHFvGyjdHNfUjcLeLIlllWlwZA0EP8UlHrZCglOgQjnyyXF9NieEQqEUxfTiqQh2LTAmWoHuq2cQebaHBHYsZCyW5ZAOmmXZCMfC6k7wdrvD1nqA0OokJg5aiL0N7qm1zZC4E9OElZAN7r8FyMZAWHmQfg910PyLG7OXaaZB4ZD&__paging_token=enc_AdDjgl8J8ah7EkRm6ANkMzNaxRYdGGE7wGUpMEC7LqLKmzi21Wm4IP1Mg8tc2BZBSUJEgZAm6TlmDySTWr7hoqfKwR&__previous=1",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/6604386669/posts?fields=shares,created_time,permalink_url&limit=25&format=json&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBACipMCOGXLzMceEqHFvGyjdHNfUjcLeLIlllWlwZA0EP8UlHrZCglOgQjnyyXF9NieEQqEUxfTiqQh2LTAmWoHuq2cQebaHBHYsZCyW5ZAOmmXZCMfC6k7wdrvD1nqA0OokJg5aiL0N7qm1zZC4E9OElZAN7r8FyMZAWHmQfg910PyLG7OXaaZB4ZD&until=1488618000&__paging_token=enc_AdC8UoxF4N2jCIoT2POGWgsxrPdVtNkEJHpCN5badU5rBQqS9ZAoRfq4RPsMDpCKR9oqAO9gj241ngm8ZBDpZC5kGGI"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about `Json Parsing` in Java. You may try it: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for REST?
There are many webservices out there like we have Spring Webservices.